# How do I make a radio button selection convert to a string and put it into EditText?

Tags: android, string, int, android-edittext, radio-group

I am trying to login to my website and need to figure out how to convert a radioButton choice into a string and then convert it into an EditText.

```
public class HttpLogin extends Activity {
    private Button login;
    private EditText company, username, password;
    private int radioCheckedId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioCompany); 
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                radioCheckedId = checkedId;
                if(radioCheckedId==1){
                    company=R.string.a_e;
                }
                if(radioCheckedId==2){
                    company=R.string.stat_o;
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please choose a company.",
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                String mCompany = company.getText().toString();
                String mUsername = username.getText().toString();
                String mPassword = password.getText().toString();

                tryLogin(mCompany, mUsername, mPassword);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the reference of the Radio Group and then find the selected radio button by using the getCheckedInId method of radio group,then get the radio button corresponding to that id and then call getText method on that.

Hope this will help you!!